# Can I have concentric Tiny Huts?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, rituals

Leomund's tiny hut makes a 10' radius dome shaped barrier. As a ritual, this takes 11 minutes to cast.

We're thinking of luring the bad guys to our tiny hut and using it for tactical advantages. If the party stops for a short rest (60 minutes) can I cast Leomund's tiny hut as a ritual a total of 5 times (55 minutes) with them inside?

This way, a total of 5 dispel magics would need to be cast on it to break through, thus taxing enemy actions and spell slots. Is there a limit to the number of Leomund's tiny huts I can nest this way without spell slots (other than the 43 times we'd have time for 8*60/11)?

The reason I think this is possible is because PHB p204 says under "A Clear Path to the Target" that if you place an area of effect in a place where there's an obstruction, it comes into being on the near side of the obstruction. Suggesting that multiple layers of Leomund's tiny hut can be cast concentrically.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is a duplicate, but let us know how it's not and the community can determine what to do. Otherwise, duplicates are super helpful for different ways of asking a question and helping others find this answer.

Comment: Even if this was possible it wouldn't work. Tiny Hut allows passage based on who was inside at the time so the enemies could simply leave.